# Is the background-blend-mode not supported in Edge / IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge, background-blend-mode

I am curious why this doesn't work in MS Edge / IE browsers.
Is the blend-mode property not available there? I was not able to dig up any information on it.

```
.blended {
  background-image: url(image.png);
  background-color: red;
  background-blend-mode: multiply;
}
```

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#search=background-blend-mode

Comment: That was a very useful page! Thank you. =)

Comment: FINALLY under construction! Just FYI. https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/status/backgroundblendmode/?q=background%20blend%20mode

Answer (score 5):

[no, it is not currently supported in Edge](http://caniuse.com/#search=background-blend-mode)

It is currently "[on the backlog](https://dev.modern.ie/platform/status/backgroundblendmode/)", meaning the team is planning on working on it, but hasn't started yet.

As with all features in Edge, if you [vote up](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/257854-microsoft-edge-developer/suggestions/9434463-background-blend-mode) the feature on the Edge uservoice, it will be more likely to be implemented sooner.